# Cannot find mpmath package in python

Tags: python

I am using `Python35`. I would like to use the `mpmath.invertlaplace` function used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774915/laplace-inverse-in-python-with-mpmath). Unfortunately I am having some trouble:

```
 >>> import mpmath as mp
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def f(s):
    return(1/s)

>>> t = np.linspace(0.01,0.5,10)
>>> G = []
>>> for i in range(0,10):
    G.append(mp.invertlaplace(f, t[i], method = 'dehoog', degree = 18))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#254>", line 2, in <module>
    G.append(mp.invertlaplace(f, t[i], method = 'dehoog', degree = 18))
AttributeError: module 'mpmath' has no attribute 'invertlaplace'
```

Has this function been added too recently for Python35 to pick up? Am I missing something here? I feel like this should work...

Comment: Update the package to a recent version?

Comment: I am using pip... How do I do that?

Comment: `pip install mpmath --upgrade` ?

Comment: When I upgrade I get`Requirement already up-to-date: mpmath in c:\python35\lin\site-packages` I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Still getting same error

Comment: In this case the package in the pip repo just doesn't have this function. Not much to do except finding the package elsewhere and installing it manually.